# RealmCollectionChange reports modifications even though there's none

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Here's my setup:

On every `UIViewController viewWillAppear` method I fetch data from the server. Data is parsed into realm objects which later added to Realm DB. I've setup a notification block to report if any changes occur to the results. Now, the problem is that even though fetched objects are identical to the ones already written to DB, `RealmCollectionChange` still reports as if all objects were modified. Here's a sample code:

Fetching / Parsing:

```
realmDB.beginWrite()

for projectJSON in projectsArray {
   let project = createObjectFromJson(projectJSON)
   realmDB.add(project, update: true)
}

realmDB.commitWrite()
```

Change Observer:

```
notificationToken = projects.addNotificationBlock { changes in
switch changes {
case .Update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
    ...
}
```

So here, modifications always return full list of indexes as if all objects have been updated.

Is that expected? Any way to avoid that behavior? Seems as `add:update` forces an update as opposed to skipping an update if objects are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your createObjectFromJson method, you are almost certainly setting object properties regardless of whether they have changed. Unfortunately, setting a property is detected as a modification even if the value was the same. I'm not sure if this is intended behavior, but one way to get around this is to only set the property if the new value is not equal to the old, though this may get ugly.

Comment: This is correct. Changing a property, even if it's to the same value will register as a modification in the notifications. This is to ensure that the UI is always given a chance to update when an object has been touched by a write transaction. If you have a specific use case where this is clashing with your app's implementation, please file an issue on the Realm Cocoa repo: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues